# Linux: Load debug symbols on CentOS v7

Tags: linux, centos, segmentation-fault, gdb

There are a number of system seeing segmentation faults when exercising basic commands like `cd`, `ls`, `sudo reboot`, and `make`.  This doesn't happen all the time and appears intermittent and a physical reboot will help for a period of time.  We were able to cause a segmentation fault for executing `sudo true`.  Attached gdb and getting the backtrace yields:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f71c45a98a1 in sudo_sss_setdefs () from /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f71c45a98a1 in sudo_sss_setdefs () from /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
#1  0x00007f71c45a1ca4 in sudoers_policy_init () from /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
#2  0x00007f71c459bb37 in sudoers_policy_open () from /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
#3  0x000055f13bdbd55b in main ()
```

The question I have is how would I load the debug symbols into gdb?  If I recall, on Windows, MS would release debug symbols for developers to use.  I am not sure if debug symbols are released for Linux distros and may be distro related.

Secondary question would be, what is the best approach to debug segmentation faults other than using gdb?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> how would I load the debug symbols into gdb?

You install a `sudo-dbg` or similar package (that is, if program X comes from package `foo`, then debug symbols for X will be in `foo-dbg` (or similar named) package).

> on Windows, MS would release debug symbols for developers to use.

Most Linux distributions contain the `*-dbg` packages.

> what is the best approach to debug segmentation faults other than using gdb?

The symptoms you described (different commands crashing, crash going away for a while after reboot) suggest that this is a problem with RAM on your system.

If you have faulty RAM, debugging individual programs is unlikely to yield anything useful. Instead, use `memtest86` to thoroughly exercise your memory.

Comment: Thanks for the information and suggestion for `memtest`.  Took a while, but found a RedHat article talking about debug symbols [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/intro.debuginfo) which they call them `debuginfo`.